# I don't understand why my buy transaction failed. I was buying a new coin on uniswap and compared to another person's TX, my one failed. Please Help

Tags: solidity, transactions, etherscan, uniswap

so I was attempting a transaction, as you can see in my transaction, I wanted to spend the amount highlighted in the picture around 0.02 ETH. I paid extra for gas to make sure my TX would be quicker. Then I saw another transaction that was successful however this one had a higher value of 0.1 ETH. I understand that with new coins there are limits to how much someone can buy so perhaps that's why my transaction failed. But what I don't understand is why does their transaction have a higher value than mine but despite that manages to go through? Unlike my transaction, this person's TX has internal transactions but mine doesn't. Please help as I'm a bit confused about this. Thanks

The links to my Transaction and the person in question's Transaction are:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07fdf7a1aed7fb3e313a20c4a5954c7204032d50b73a27429f3b598d9e93135e
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5abeef45172aef786142f24b64fff5308fe22b8d520ec8335e6ff1484fc63816

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare two transactions(at the bottom of the tx page, `Click to see more`), difference is:
Method: you call to `swapExactETHForTokens`, others call to `swapETHForExactTokens`.

`swapExactETHForTokens`: spend exact ethers along with the TX, 0.022416355748973361 for your case, to get some target tokens.

`swapETHForExactTokens`: to get exact target tokens, spend ethers( amount depends on realtime price).

> I paid extra for gas to make sure my TX would be quicker.

It won't work, instead, increase gas price to make your TX quicker.

Uniswap offical docs:
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v2/reference/smart-contracts/common-errors

> UniswapV2: TRANSFER_FAILED
> This means the core contract was unable to send tokens to the recipient. This is most likely due to a scam token, where the token owner has maliciously disabled the transfer function in a way that allows users to buy the token, but not sell them.

The target token Floki Max (FMAX) may have unusual logic that block your TX.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand what the issue was now.